Giving Torah's relationship advice to someone who is in a forbidden relationship
(There are several levels to this, and perhaps I should split this answer up)

If a Jew is in a forbidden marriage

If a Jew is in a mixed "marriage"

If a Jew is in a relationship with another Jew out of wedlock

If a Jew is dating a non Jew


If any of the above come asking for relationship advice or help with their relationship in general, are we allowed to give Torah's marriage advice? Are there guidelines this?
And if the answer is no, then are we allowed to ever give advice to someone without knowing their situation? Maybe they are asking for the wrong reasons.

Why does the title read "Torah's relationship advice", what is it? Did you mean "Jewish"?

There's a bunch of positive and negative Mitzvos that support helping a Jew in [spiritual] distress: like והאבת, לא תעמוד, לא תוכל להתעלם, and more. All Kiruv organizations follow those guidelines and provide counseling on this very subject.

I asked this question to a knowledgable friend of mine, a community Rabbi, the son of great Rabbis, who gave some of his own thoughts about 3. One should not rely on this answer in practical situations as per site policy (and common sense), especially as I am openly admitting these are just some thoughts.
Firstly, one might say that they are in some sense "married" (Rama, Even HaEzer 26:1). Even if not, one should give the advice, based on a couple of principles.

There is a principle in Chassidus that if one is going to do something, one should do it all the way. One shouldn't do the wrong thing of course, but one shouldn't do things half way in general. This is because doing something all the way means one is increasing enthusiasm in their life, and enthusiasm is the ticket to joy. Joy is so important for a person in so many ways, and is a very real catalyst for them to do teshuva. So, if they are in a relationship, help them do it properly.
By giving them this advice at a time when they will not use it properly, one can hope that they will remember the advice and one day end up using it properly, so it is not necessarily wasted or squandered. In fact, by demonstrating the Torah's Chochma, one will help the Jew realise that the Torah is his portion and will be encouraged to do teshuva.

These points in theory can be used in the other situations as well, but it would be best for everyone to ask their own Rav what to do in these situations.
